# What is the difference between name , beanName and mappedName attributes for annotation @EJB?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb-3.0

What is the difference between `name`, `beanName` and `mappedName` attributes for annotation `@EJB` in EJB3.0?
I found this on net at following link -
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ejb/ejb_annotations.htm

- `name` - Used to specify *name* which will be used to locate *the referenced bean* in environment.
- `beanName` - Used to provide *name* of *the referenced bean*.
- `mappedName` - Used to specify *the JNDI name* of *the referenced bean*.

How do the *name* in `name` and `beanName` attribute differ ?

Comment: The name being referred is ambiguous because it can be a string value from any of these options :  (1)Name of the Java file e.g. BeanA or (2)with package name com.xyz.BeanA or (3) java:comp/env/BeanA. please use this info.

Answer (score 4):

The `@EJB` declares an EJB reference from your component to a target EJB.  The `name` is the key of the reference in your component environment. There are several ways to specify the target EJB:

1. The `beanName` (or `<ejb-link>` in XML) can be used to specify the target EJB if the EJB is located in the same application as your component
2. The `mappedName` is a non-portable, vendor-specific string (even though it's part of the standard!) that somehow identifies the target.
3. In EJB 3.1, the `lookup` is a portable way to specify a JNDI string of the target.
4. Vendor-specific mechanisms, such as binding files.
5. If none of the other mechanisms are used, then the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJB.html) says the `@EJB` will target an EJB in the same application that implements the target type if there is only one.